# bokeh x-axis datetime returning incorrect dates

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have a dataframe `df2` with dates in string form and numbers

```
date       |    value
2018-02-02    130
2018-02-05    360
2018-02-06    98
2018-02-07    150
```

When I plot the dates in a plot along the x axis, the dates returned are incorrect. They seem to translate like so:

`2018-02-06 = Jan 1, 1970
2018-02-05 = Jan 13.5, 1970`

```
source=ColumnDataSource(data=df2)
p= figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=400, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.xaxis.formatter= DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%B/%d/%Y")
p.triangle("DATE","VALUE",color='black',source=source)
```

The glyphs don't fall exactly on the gridlines either. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`p.triangle(df2["DATE"].dt.date,df2["VALUE"],color='Black')` will yield the date

I have a nasty habit of finding the right answers shortly after posting it on stackoverflow. I think I may do that more often!